# How to add existing solution to subversion - Ankhsvn not showing file tree

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

I am trying to add an existing Visual Studio solution to Subversion using AnkhSVN.  I have tried to follow the simple instructions from places like here:

http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/com.collabnet.doc.anksvn_001/action/ankh_add_soln.html

In all of the help files I have accessed, there is a file tree when they add their subversion location.  When I go to add it, there is no file tree in my repository (see top image).  Notice there is no "+" to open the file tree.  I also cannot select the "Create Folder..." button.

When I log in on my browser, I can see a file tree (see bottom image).

Since I can't select a folder in the repository, it says, "Please select a valid location in the repository to add to".

[image]

I would only like answers on how to use AnkhSVN through Visual Studio please, not some other program.

Visual Studio 2017 Professional/15.0.0+26228.9

AnkhSVN 2.7.12815.35086

Comment: From your image it seems that you did only enter a server URL but not a repository

Answer (score 1):

As @royalITS mentioned, it seems as though you didn't enter an actual repository in which to create a folder. In my experience with Ankh, you have to know the name of an existing Repo before you can add a project to SVN--there doesn't seem to be a way to browse for existing repos (which is unfortunate if you don't know the name of any).

So if I enter just my SVN server location I can't create a project folder:

[image: Attempting to create folder in SVN server location]

But if I then add the name of a known repo to the URL and select it, I can then Create Folder:

[image: Attempting to create folder in SVN repo]

Hopefully that will get you on the right track.